# Topological properties of convex sets

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I was trying to prove some 'facts' regarding convex sets which seem natural, but I seem to stuck, so I was wondering whether tbey are indeed true, which I'll describe below.

Let $X$ be a topological vector space and let $K_1,K_2\subseteq X$ be closed convex subsets. I think the following are true:

1. If $\text{int}(K_1)\neq \emptyset$, then $\overline{ \text{int}(K_1) }=K_1$.
2. If $\partial K_1=\partial K_2$, then $\text{ext}(K_1)=\text{ext}(K_2)$.

I'm assuming there are counter-examples to these facts, but I can't think of any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is true. The inclusion $\overline{\operatorname{int} K_1} \subset K_1$ holds for all closed $K_1$, convex or not. To see the other inclusion, fix $a \in \operatorname{int} K_1$. For every $b \in K_1$,
$$\gamma_b \colon t \mapsto a + t(b-a),\quad t \in [0,1]$$
is a path in $K_1$ connecting $a$ and $b$, and $\gamma_b(t) \in \operatorname{int} K_1$ for $t \in [0,1)$ since
$$(1-t)\cdot (\operatorname{int} K_1) + tb$$
is an open neighbourhood of $\gamma_b(t)$ contained in $K_1$. Then $b = \lim_{t \to 1} \gamma_b(t)$ shows $b \in \overline{\operatorname{int} K_1}$.

The second doesn't hold. Trivial counterxample: $K_1 = \varnothing$ and $K_2 = X$.

Slightly less trivial counterexample: Let $H$ be a closed hyperplane<sup>(1)</sup> in $X$ (if that doesn't exist, the trivial counterexample might be the only one in $X$). We can take $K_1$ to be one of the closed half-spaces determined by $H$ and $K_2$ to be either $H$, or the other closed half-space determined by $H$. Then $\partial K_1 = H = \partial K_2$, but the exteriors are different ($\operatorname{int} K_1$ is contained in $\operatorname{ext} K_2$ and not empty).

I don't know if there are other counterexamples. I couldn't think of any, but neither do I see a proof that there are no others.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Viewing $X$ as a real vector space, even if it also is a complex vector space.

Comment: Hi, could you explain to me because $\gamma(t):=[(1-t)\cdot\big(\text{int}(K_1)\big)+tb]\notin\partial(K_1)$ for any $t\in[0,1)$? Unfortunately I don't understand it.

Comment: For $t \in [0,1)$, the set $(1-t)\cdot \operatorname{int}(K_1)$ is open (it's the product of a nonzero scalar with an open set), hence $(1 - t) \operatorname{int}(K_1) + tb$ is an open neighbourhood of the point $(1-t)a + tb$. Since $K_1$ is convex, this set is contained in $K_1$. As an open subset of $K_1$ it's a subset of $\operatorname{int}(K_1)$, and therefore doesn't intersect the boundary.

Comment: Okay, so since $\text{int}(K_1)\subseteq\text{cl}\big(\text{int}(K_1)\big)$ we have only to prove that $\text{Bd}(S)\subseteq\text{cl}\big(\text{int}(K_1)$.

Comment: So we know that $\text{cl}(K_1)$ is convex because $K_1$ is convex. Now if $b\in\text{Bd}(K_1)$ then $b\in\text{cl}(K_1)$ and so $\gamma_b(t)\in\text{cl}(K_1)$ for any $a\in\text{int}(K_1)$ and for any $\delta>0$ there exist $t\in[0,1)$ such that $\gamma_b(t)\in B(b,\delta)$ so we have only to prove that $\gamma_b(t)\in\text{int}(K_1)$. So why if $t\in[0,1)$ then necessarly $\gamma_b(t)\in\text{int}(K_1)$? Could you explain this to me, please? Forgive my confusion.

Comment: So I substantially suppose that $K_1$ is not closed and so $\text{Bd}(K_1)\nsubseteq K_1$.

Comment: Anyway I post an apposite question about this problem: if you like you can answer to it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3830964/prove-that-if-a-in-textints-and-b-in-textcls-then-a-b-in-textint#3830964)

Comment: Did Olivier's answer over there clarify everything for you, or is there something left to explain?