# If $S$ is convex then $\text{cl}\big(\text{int}(S)\big)=\text{cl}(S)$ when $\text{int}(S)\neq\emptyset$

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

**Definition**

Let be $X$ a topological vector space. A subset $S$ of $X$ is said convex if the affine combination
$$
A:=\{z\in X: z=(1-t)x+ty, t\in[0,1]\}
$$
is contained in $S$ for any $x, y\in S$.

**Statement**

If $S$ is convex and $\text{int}(S)\neq\emptyset$ then $\text{cl}\big(\text{int}(S)\big)=\text{cl}(S)$.

Clearly $\text{int}(S)\subseteq S$ and so $\text{cl}\big(\text{int}(S)\big)\subseteq\text{cl}(S)$. Then if $x\in\text{cl}(S)$ then or $x\in\text{int}(S)$ and so $x\in\text{cl}\big(\text{int}(S)\big)$ either $x\in\text{Bd}(S)$ and so we only to prove that $\text{Bd}(S)\subseteq\text{cl}\big(\text{int}(S)\big)$ but unfortunately I don't be able to prove this. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: False. Consider a line segment in $\mathbb R^{2}$.

Comment: Okay, and if $\text{C}\neq\emptyset$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3777446/topological-properties-of-convex-sets?rq=1

Comment: Unfortunately in the answer you link I don't understand why $\gamma(t):=[(1-t)\cdot\big(\text{int}(K_1)\big)+tb]\notin\partial(K_1)$ for any $t\in[0,1)$. So could you explain this to me, please?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro For $t \in [0,1)$, the map $\phi_t(u) = (1-t)u + tb$ is defined on $\text{int}(K_1)$ and is bijective. It maps any open ball centered on $x \in \text{int}(K_1)$ into an open ball included in $K_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to [Topological properties of convex sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3777446) shows that if $K_1$ is closed and convex and $\operatorname{int}(K_1) \ne \emptyset$, then $\operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{int}(K_1)) =  K_1$. The present question asks to prove the following more general theorem:

> If $S$ is convex and $\operatorname{int}(S) \ne \emptyset$, then $\operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{int}(S)) =  \operatorname{cl}(S)$.

$\operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{int}(S)) \subset \operatorname{cl}(S)$ is obvious. It remains to prove that if $b \in \operatorname{cl}(S)$, then $b \in \operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{int}(S))$. This means to show that for each open  neighborhood $U$ of $b$ in $X$ there exists $b_U  \in U \cap \operatorname{int}(S)$.

We know that there exists $c_U \in U \cap S$. Fix $a \in \operatorname{int}(S)$. The set $(1-t)\operatorname{int}(S)$ is open in $X$ for $t \ne 1$ because multiplication by a non-zero factor is a homeomorphism on $X$. Hence $\Omega(t) = (1-t)\operatorname{int}(S) + tc_U$ is open in $X$ for $t \ne 1$ because each translation is a homeomorphism on $X$. We have

1. $(1-t)a + t c_U \in \Omega(t)$.
2. $\Omega(t) \subset S$ for $t \in [0,1]$ since each point of $\Omega(t)$ has the form $(1-t)c + tc_U$ with $c \in \operatorname{int}(S) \subset S$ and $c_U \in S$.
3. $\Omega(t) \subset \operatorname{int}(S)$ for $t \in [0,1)$ beause $\Omega(t)$ is an *open* subset of $S$ for $t \ne 1$.

The function $\gamma : [0,1] \to X, \gamma(t) = a + t(c_U-a) = (1-t)a + tc_U$, is continuous with $\gamma(1) = c_U \in U$, thus $\gamma(t) \in U$ for $t \in (1-\epsilon,1]$. Hence for $t \in (1-\epsilon,1)$ we see that $b_U  = (1-t)a + tc_U \in U \cap \Omega(t) \subset U \cap \operatorname{int}(S)$. Note that the constant maps $\phi(t) = a$ and $\psi(t) = c_U-a$ are continuous and that $\iota(t) = 1-t$ is continuous. Thus 3. and 4. below  show that $\gamma$ is continuous.

**Edited:**

A (real or complex) topological vector space is vector space $X$ endowed with a topology such that addition $\alpha : X \times X \to X, \alpha(x,y ) = x+y$, and scalar multiplication $\mu : \mathbb K \times X \to X, \mu(r,x) = r \cdot x$, are continuous. Here $\mathbb K = \mathbb R, \mathbb C$. It is an easy exercise to show that normed linear spaces are topological vector spaces (the topology is of course the norm-topology).

1. Multiplication by a non-zero factor is a homeomorphism on $X$:
   The map $i_r : X \to \mathbb K \times X, i_r(x) = (x,r)$, is continuous for all $r \in \mathbb K$. Hence $\mu_r = \mu \circ i_r : X \to X$ is continuous. If $r \ne 0$, then also $\mu_{1/r} : X \to X$ is continuous. Clearly $\mu_r \circ  \mu_{1/r} = id$ and $\mu_{1/r} \circ \mu_r = id$, thus $\mu_r$ is a homeomorphism with inverse $\mu_{1/r}$.
2. Each translation is a homeomorphism on $X$: The map $j_b : X \to X \times X, j_b(b) = (x,b)$, is continuous for all $b \in X$. Hence $\alpha_b = \alpha \circ j_b : X \to X$ is continuous. Clearly $\alpha_b \circ \alpha_{-b} = id$ and $\alpha_{-b} \circ \alpha_b = id$, thus $\alpha_b$ is a homeomorphism with inverse $\alpha_{-b}$.
3. If $r : Y \to \mathbb K$ and $f : Y \to X$ are continuous, then $r\cdot f : Y \to X, (r \cdot f)(y) = r(y) \cdot f(y)$, is continuous: The diagonal map $d : Y \to Y \times Y, d(y) = (y,y)$, is continuous. Thus $r \cdot f = \mu \circ (r \times f) \circ d$ is continuous.
4. The sum of continuous functions $f,g: Y \to X$ is continuous: We have $f + g = \alpha \circ (f \times g) \circ d$.

Comment: Okay, only for completeness I ask if what I to follow observe about your proof is correct. So I want uickly prove that the multiplications by a non-zero factor and the traslations are homeomorphism.

Comment: So clearly they are bjection so we hava to prove that the are continuous and open.

Comment: If $A$ is open then for any $x\in A$ there exist $\delta>0$ such that $B(x,\delta)\subseteq A$ and so it is sufficent to prove that the set $f^{-1}[B(x,\delta)]$ and $f[B(x,\delta)]$ are open wegere $f$ is a scalar multiplication by not-zer factor or a traslation.

Comment: Now let be $\lambda(x):=\lambda\cdot x$ for some (real or complex) scalar $\lambda$. So $\lambda[B(x,\delta)]$ b is an open ball of radius $|\lambda|\cdot\delta$ that is clearly open. Similarly $\frac 1 \lambda B(x,\delta)=\lambda^{-1}[B(x,\delta)]$ is an open ball of radius $\delta$. So we conclude that the multiplication by a non-zero factor is an homeomorphism.

Comment: Now let be $v(x):=x+v$ for some vector $v$. So we observe that $B(x+v,\delta)=v[B(x,\delta)]]$  is an open ball of radius $\delta>0$. Similarly $B(x-v,\delta)=v^{-1}[B(x,\delta)]$ is a ball of radius $\delta$. So finally we conclude that the traslation are homeomorphism.

Comment: So is correct what I wrote?

Comment: It is correct, but it only covers normed linear spaces. I shall edit my answer to treat the general case.

Comment: Okay, but don't delete what you wrote before: it is usefull!!!!!

Comment: So if you say that what I wrote it is true only for normed space. How to prove that the above functions are homeomorphism in the case where a topological vector space is not a normed space?

Comment: Okay, all clear. Only I want point out that you wrote $\mu\circ\mu_{\frac 1 r}=id$ but I think you wanted write $\mu_r\circ\mu_{\frac 1 r}=id$, right?

Comment: Yes, corrected!

Comment: Okay. Thanks too much for your assistance!!! If I don't bother you, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829558/if-s-is-convex-then-textcls-and-textints-are-convex-too) too, please?

Comment: Anyway I have a little doubt. We know that $\text{cl}(S)$ is convex becauser $S$ is convex. Now if $b\in\text{Bd}(S)$ then $b\in\text{cl}(S)$ and so $\gamma(t)\in\text{cl}(S)$ for any $a\in\text{int}(S)$ and for any $\delta>0$ there exist $t\in[0,1)$ such that $\gamma(t)\in B(b,\delta)$ so that we have only to prove that $\gamma(t)\in\text{int}(S)$. So why if $t\in[0,1)$ then necessarly $\gamma(t)\in\text{int}(S)$? Could you explain this to me, please? Forgive my confusion.

Comment: The problem is that in the answer I posted it is hypothesized that $K_1$ is closed but here I did not hypothesize this for $S$. So generally why if $a\in\text{int}(S)$ and $b\in\text{cl}(S)$ then $\gamma(t)\in\text{int}(S)$ for any $t\in[0,1)$?

Comment: Please read my edit.

Comment: Okay, all clear. I only ask if I understood precisely the continuity of $\gamma(t)$. So to see the continuity of $\gamma(t)$ we define $\phi(t):=t(c_U-a)$ for any $t\in[0,1]$ and $\psi(x)=a+x$ for any $x\in X$ that are continuous because the scalar multiplication is continuos to be $X$ a T.V.S. and because the traslations are homeomorphism: so the continuity of $\gamma$ derived by the fact that $\gamma=\psi\circ\phi$, right?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: Okay, thanks too much!!! You was very courteous with me.